# referencing user guide or manual

Tags: bibliographies

I am referencing a manual using the code:

```
@manual{pdp90amanual,
author = {Thorlabs},
title = {PDP90A Position Sensing Detector User Guide},
date = {2015-11-6},
language = {English},
version = {},
organization = {Thorlabs},
pagetotal = {12},
pubstate = {November 6, 2015},
}
```

The output I get is:

> Newport.Compact photonics control solutions. English. Newport. Jan. 2015. 7 pp.January, 2015.

What is the difference between `date` and `pubstate`?

Whenever I try to comment one of them out, I get an error, so clearly they are both necessary. The example I saw, gave both fields the same date, which makes me think it was just a coincidence. But now I don't know what each field indicates, so please help me understand if you know the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual of the `biblatex` package, both are data fields (see sec. 2.2.2 in the [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).)

`pubstate` indicates, if the manual is `in press`, `prepublished`, etc. See also section 4.9.2.11 in the manual.

Hence, you're using the field wrong in your example.

## Example

Assuming the manual is forthcoming, `pubstate` would contain the word like shown below.

```
@manual{pdp90amanual,
author = {Thorlabs},
title = {PDP90A Position Sensing Detector User Guide},
date = {2015-11-6},
language = {English},
version = {},
organization = {Thorlabs},
pagetotal = {12},
pubstate = {forthcoming},
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Am I right in the assumption that if there is a date, then it is always prepublished? 
Otherwise, how do I tell if a manual is prepublished or in press?

Comment: @Reem no. if it has a date, it is published. `prepublished` means, it has been released before a specific date. usually the  publisher gives notice or the document itself contains information about the state a document is in. in your case I'd assume it has been published. and from what I see, the manual is final.